# how to create a php ternary expression containing only if statement

Tags: php, ternary

How can I create a php ternary expression containing just if statement without the else part? This is what I tried :

```
$vn = condition ? expression1 ;
```

And this is what I'm trying to achieve

```
if(condition) {
    $vn = expression1;
}
```

to

```
$vn = condition ? expression1 ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the same variable in the `else` part:

```
$vn = condition ? expression1 : $vn ;
```

Note this creates a notice if `$vn` was not used before.

Comment: You could use `@$vn` in the `else` part to prevent the notice.

Comment: @Barmar yes. But in fact you should initialise `$vn` first. Suppressing notices, warnings and errors is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 7, you may want to consider the `Null Coalescing Operator`.

In certain cases, the syntax is similar to what you seem to be looking for:

```
$email = $_POST['email'] ?? 'none';

// is the same as:
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : 'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(condition) AND ($vn = expression1);
```

works too.

And only as info:

```
$v = condition?:expression1
```

is also possible, here the `condition` (in case) is parsed to `$v`